# Adding booleans in Python

Tags: python

On rating python quizzes on Solo Learn, I came across a rather puzzling quiz. In it, it assigns booleans to three variables, then prints the sum of them to the console. The answer appears to be consisting of a single character, but I have no idea what it does, and can't find any resources on this.

The code:

```
a = 4
b = 4
c = 5
x = a == b
y = a == c
a = a != b
puzzle = x + y + a
print (puzzle)
```

What's going on with this code?

Comment: booleans are basically integers in Python, where``True`` equals ``1`` and ``False``  equals ``0``. You can check with ``print( 1 == True )``, which prints ``True``.

Answer (score 4):

When added, `True` is converted to `1`, and `False` to `0`. Some examples:

```
print(True + True) # 2

print(True + True + True) # 3

print(False + False) # 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, Booleans are actually Integers under the hood, both `False == 0` and `True == 1` evaluate to `True`. So with your code example, puzzle evaluates to `1`.